# In Scala 3, how to summon a constant from its type?

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-3, singleton-type

assuming that I want to summon a constant 3 from its type `3`.

In Scala 2, this can be easily done with shapeless Witness:

```
val w = implicitly[Witness[3]]
w.value
```

this has no counterpart in Scala 3, I've tried the following:

```
  val v2 = summon[3]

  val v3 = inline constValue[3]
```

and none of them appears to be working. What's the canonical way to implement this? And what can be done to make it cross-compilable between Scala 3 & 2.13?

Comment: `summon[ValueOf[3]].value` or something like that. `ValueOf` is the typeclass you want.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez much obliged, this should be the canonical answer. I still find this compiler implementation weird & undocumented, `summon[3]` should've been much better

Comment: Not sure how `summon[3]` could ever work, also `ValueOf` is not a compiler implementation, is just a regular typeclass defined in stdlib land, and is not undocumented. Plus, it was the right thing to do even in `2.13`

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to do all that, you can just use `valueOf[3]` _(lowercase `v`)_ and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala 3 use `scala.compiletime.constValue` (documented [here](https://github.com/scala/scala3/blob/release-3.4.1/library/src/scala/compiletime/package.scala#L109-L112))

```
constValue[3]
```

or good old Scala 2 type class `scala.ValueOf`

```scala
valueOf[3]  // from scala.runtime.stdLibPatches.Predef
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/puPRyLUgQmaVfXslE7Di7Q/8

`implicitly[ValueOf[3]].value` should be cross-compilable between Scala 3 & 2.13 as long as `implicitly` exists in Scala 3.

`summon[3]` can't be correct because `3` is not an implicit.

Comment: canonical, tho I see all the reasons it should be